# Send Decimal number from HTML but as Integer on MVC C# ,ASP Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, double

I'm trying to send a decimal number from html to c# via a form, but it gets caught as an integer.does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without all the details, I would check two things:

1. The model so that it matches
2. Check to see if I'm taking into account Culture relevant details. In some countries the dot (.) that separates the decimals is not the same. Some cultures use comma (,) to separate decimals and thus, you'll get the integer value, as the default culture fallback.